# wshShell.SendKeys(Chr(175)) doesn't work

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to write a script that will be turning the volume up in Wndows 10. But there's a problem because this particular keystroke that cranks volume up doesn't work. The mute and volume down works perfectly.

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

For i = 0 To 50
    wshShell.SendKeys(Chr(175))
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) tool.

Example :

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Increase the system volume by 20000 units (out of 65535)
WshShell .Run("nircmd.exe changesysvolume 20000")

' Decrease the system volume by 5000 units
WshShell .Run("nircmd.exe changesysvolume -5000")
```